# Compability JDBC driver versions and PostgreSQL versions

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

Can anyone point me on where to find an exact documenation which postgreSQL database version requires which JDBC driver version?

In the case at hand I want to know: What is the minimum required JDBC version in a Java server application connecting to a database of version PostgreSQL 11.13?

Unfortunately the PostgreSQL JDBC Driver website is not really precise on this:

> The current version of the driver **should be compatible** with PostgreSQL
> 8.2 and higher, and Java 6 (JDBC 4.0), Java 7 (JDBC 4.1), Java 8 (JDBC 4.2) and Java 9.

https://jdbc.postgresql.org/about/about.html

Comment: The latest version of the driver should work on PostgreSQL 8.2 and higher. The should is likely because they don't test all versions and will rely on user bug reports instead. However, this sounds like an off-topic question to me, opinion based cq asking for recommendations. I think it is better to address this question to the pgsql-jdbc mailing list.

Comment: Does this answer your question?  https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html.  (Just one click away from the link in your question.)

Comment: Also note that the version number was changed to reflect that basically all current drivers should be compatible with Postgresql 8.2+: "The naming scheme previously has 9.4 in it which leads people to believe it is for server version 9.4 only, when in fact it support PostgreSQL 8.2 and higher. " For best support I'd recommend using the newest driver compatible with the Java version that's used though and given the fact that almost everyone should run on at least Java 8 for various reasons users should be able to just pick any driver version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question is a wrong one. Why would you want to use a JDBC driver that has as many bugs as possible?

Rather, you want to ask what the oldest version is that the latest JDBC driver supports, and [the documentation](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/) will tell you that

> [...] nning old applications or JVMs), this is the driver you should be using. It supports PostgreSQL 8.2 or newer and requires Java 6 or newer.

Always use the latest JDBC driver, and you won't go wrong.

Comment: This link returns a 404 but I don't know the correct location so I can't fix it.